# Add Facebook SDK to android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, sdk

I am trying to add the facebook sdk to my android project in eclipse. I have tried a lot of toturial that I found in the interne but none hase worked for me.
doese someone now houe to add the sdk to android eclips projetcs?

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I gess you are triyng to add facebook sdk to a legacy code so you can check
[Android facebook SDK as JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036465/android-facebook-sdk-as-jar)
else i recommend using android studio.